# Call child Fragment method from parent fragment when child view is available?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-nested-fragment

I have searched for solution and found so many cases (not relevant to my situation or **may be i didn't understood** them properly).

My case is :
Let's say i have one parent  **Fragment Parent;**

And i'm creating two child fragments form parent fragment's **onCreateView**

```
ChildFragment1 child1 = new ChildFragment1();
ChildFragment2 child2 = new ChildFragment2();


 //My child fragment exactly looks like this
 public class ChildFragment1 extends Fragment {

    View rootView;
    public ChildFragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void methodTobeCalled() {
        //here i would like to do some changes to child view (add some views)
    }
}
```

i can access method of child fragment through reference of child like

```
child1.methodTobeCalled();
```

But at this time i don't have access to my child Fragment View.

**I would like to call my** *child Fragment* **function from** *parent fragment* **when i have access to child view, is there any chance?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am not getting what happen you said "i can access method of child fragment through reference of child like" but you are not able to access the views.

Comment: i have updated my question, child fragment exactly looks like that, i am getting my **rootview** as **null** @jiteshmohite

Comment: where you are initializing your views  ?

Answer (score 1):

try to attach it inside this method

```
@Override
public void onAttachFragment(Fragment childFragment) {
    super.onAttachFragment(childFragment);
}
```

Comment: I didn't get what exactly you mean

Answer (score 1):

You can archive by using **getChildFragmentManager()**.

Here is the code

`YourFragment yourFragmentinstance = (YourFragment) getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(**FRAGMENT_POSITION**);
yourFragmentinstance.yourMethod();`

**FRAGMENT_POSITION** is maybe 0,1 depends on your initialization.

Answer (score 0):

for access to `child_fragment` views from `parent_fragment`, use this code:

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);
myET = rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_my);
```